# Schematic outline selection

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How to select the outline from a schematic picture that has black background showing through? Too small of detail to use magic wand.
Can either the white outline or the black background be selected out of the schematic and drag/dropped to a new picture?

Comment: Hi Steve. Have you tried Select > Color Range yet to select either the white or the black? A screenshot of what you're working with would help.

Comment: Worked great!  I haven't done a lot with Color Range before.  Adding a new tool to the arsenal.  Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the *Color Range* option from the *Select* menu. It would be easier to select the background; and then inverse the selection.

You can also benefit from the in-built sliders to customize the selection.

Comment: @SteveArlin If the answer helped you fix your issue, you should mark it as "accepted" by clicking on the check symbol on the side!